# Graphics.Clear() inside of OnPaint() occasionally causes generic GDI+ error

Tags: .net, vb.net

I'm working on an application where the Client experiences an issue every couple months (they are able to work around the issue by restarting the application). The stack trace always points to the first line of an overridden (class inherits from `Control`) `OnPaint()` method which makes a call to `e.Graphics.Clear()`.

I have read on Microsofts Documentation that:

> The Clear method clears the state of the graphics object and should not be called when the graphics object cannot be updated. For example, if the Clear method is called on a secure desktop in a terminal server session, an ExternalException may occur, leaving the Graphics object in an inconsistent state.

I have verified that the users of the application are not running the application from a remote machine.
I have also read that:

> When overriding OnPaint in a derived class, be sure to call the base class's OnPaint method so that registered delegates receive the event.

Could the fact that the application currently does not call the base class' `OnPaint()` cause a "generic error occurred in GDI+" ExternalException error message?

Unfortunately i'm taking a stab in the dark at this issue because i cannot reproduce it and it happens very rarely in production scenarios. Could anyone provide some insight?

Comment: Many of the System.Drawing objects are disposable.  Not disposing them is a *very* common oversight.  That works for a long time, usually the GC runs often enough to prevent trouble.  Until it doesn't, then you get weirdo exceptions like this.  Use Task Manager, Processes tab.  View + Select Columns and tick GDI Objects.  Fix your code so that number stays below a couple of hundred max.

Comment: You could try catching the error

Comment: Should i be calling `dispose()` instead of `clear()` inside of the `OnPaint()` method?

Comment: You shouldn't use `dispose()` with an object you didn't already declare, So you can't use `e.Graphics.dispose()` here.

My question is for what reason you have used `e.Graphics.Clear()`?

Comment: I think the reason for using the `e.Graphics.Clear()` is to "reset" a progress bar. I'm wondering if i could simply remove this line from the `OnPaint()` method

Comment: @rage how did you write this method? with color or as is? I think you have to post your code here.

Answer (score 0):

If ***you* create** the graphics, always use it in [`Using` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):

```vb
Using gr As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(image)

    textSize = gr.MeasureString(myString, myFont) 'sample usage

End Using
```

On the other hand, **never** `Dispose()` the object which ***you* did not create**. (Including instances of `Graphics`...) When we simplifiy it, in such a case it is waiting for its '`End Using`' somewhere else – near the place where it got its '`Using`'.