# Generic error occurred in Gdi+ inside overridden OnPaint method

Tags: c#, winforms, gdi+

I am working on a user control where I want to perform some painting on it(such as DrawBorder). This works fine but ExternalException(Generic error occurred in gdi+) is thrown in one scenario where;

I  access PC1(Remote pc) from PC2 using Remote Desktop Connection. PC1(remote pc) is running my application and if I minimize RemoteDesktopConnection window on PC2.

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.Clear(Color.Black);         //Exception is thrown here

    DrawBorder(e.Graphics);

    base.OnPaint(e);
}
```

According to [MSDN page on Graphics.Clear](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.clear(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The Clear method clears the state of the graphics object and should
>   not be called when the graphics object cannot be updated. For example,
>   if the Clear method is called on a secure desktop in a terminal server
>   session, an ExternalException may occur, leaving the Graphics object
>   in an inconsistent state.

How to get rid of this issue? Is there any way I could validate graphics object before calling Clear method on it?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30037604/graphics-clear-inside-of-onpaint-occassionally-causes-generic-gdi-error) states similar kind of issue but OP of that question was not able to reproduce it. But in my case it is happening every time above code is executed with scenario specified.

Comment: If all you want is a black background, you could use `FillRectangle` instead. I realize this does not answer your question and you possibly already considered this, but who knows :)

Comment: You might find a solution here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/08eedbf7-db24-4106-9b7a-cd17a792015d/a-generic-error-occurred-in-gdi-at-systemdrawinggraphicsclearcolor-color-in-net-40?forum=winforms

Comment: @ThomasVoß, The link you provided says that capture the exception using try catch block and ignore it. Is that really the proper way to go about this?

Comment: You probably need to get ahead by asking yourself why OnPaint() runs on a control that is not visible.  You are doing something else in the rest of your code to cause that method to be called.  Hard to guess without any repro code.

Comment: @HansPassant, In my code, I have a call to `Invalidate` method. Is it possible that `OnPaint` is being called because of this even when control is not visible?

Comment: @HansPassant, I tried removing `Invalidate` method call. I'm still getting this problem. Is there any way I could track why `OnPaint` is getting called?